# Python Pandas dataframe compare rows in timeseries data

Tags: python, pandas

Fairly new to coding and pandas in general so please be kind:

I have some timeseries data that looks like this:

```
Date    Open    High    Low Close   Adj Close   Volume
2019-05-08  3.336   3.3904  3.155   3.248   3.233843    249000
2019-05-09  3.308   3.439   3.225   3.256   3.241808    229000
2019-05-10  3.269   3.386   3.15    3.173   3.15917 97000
2019-05-13  3.212   3.439   3.212   3.399   3.384185    169000
2019-05-14  3.35    3.355   3.118   3.178   3.164148    174000
2019-05-15  3.319   3.32    3.098   3.105   3.091466    156000
2019-05-16  3.023   3.095   2.994   3.076   3.062593    149000
2019-05-17  3.105   3.29    3.105   3.29    3.27566 149000
2019-05-20  3.29    3.392   3.27    3.362   3.347347    217000
2019-05-21  3.312   3.3259  3.148   3.154   3.140253    123000
```

I basicaly want to put that into a dataframe and be able to identify for which days was the close price higher than the previous day's close price. I have so far been able to put the data into a dataframe here is my code:

```
stock_data=pd.read_csv('GASX.csv', delimiter = ',',
names = ['Date', 'Open', 'Low', 'Close', 'Adj Close', 'Volume'])
```

Just need help as to how to perform the comparison

```
print(stock_data['Close'].apply(type))
Date            <class 'str'>
2019-05-08      <class 'str'>
2019-05-09      <class 'str'>
2019-05-10      <class 'str'>
2019-05-13      <class 'str'>
                   ...       
2020-05-01      <class 'str'>
2020-05-04    <class 'float'>
2020-05-05    <class 'float'>
2020-05-06    <class 'float'>
2020-05-07    <class 'float'>
Name: Close, Length: 254, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

this will create a new column, if it's 1 than this value is greater than the previous one:

```
df['Close'] = df['Close'].astype(float)
df = df.assign(higher_than_previous=df.diff().gt(0).Close.astype(int))
print(df['higher_than_previous'])
```

Comment: Thanks if I run that I see this error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: @RickStein check the new edit, I was just editing my answer

Comment: Still seeing this error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str

Comment: can you share the output if you run this code: ```print(df['close'].apply(type))```

Comment: Done I have pasted above in the question - jzk

Comment: @RickStein as you can see, you've had some strings in there which were causing the error, we cast them into floats and then we compare if it's greater than or not, I hope this will work now

Comment: Still seeing this TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: @RickStein can you share your csv file? there is no way you can get this error!

Answer (score 0):

Let us do `diff`

```
m=df['Adj Close'].diff().ge(0)
date=df.loc[m,'Date']
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed

Here is the final solution, had to list the column names:

```
cols = ['Date', 'Open', 'Low', 'Close', 'Adj Close','Volume']
stock_data = pd.read_csv('GASX.csv', header=0, names=cols)
stock_data['Close'] = pd.to_numeric(stock_data['Close'], errors='coerce')


stock_data = stock_data.assign(higher_than_previous=stock_data.diff().gt(0).Close.astype(int))
print(stock_data['higher_than_previous'])
```